# ORBEON 4.10 CE removes value in iteration template?

Tags: orbeon

When setting some value for repeated grid template my local orbeon 4.10CE is removing that value.

original tag:

```
<xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" id="repeater-template">
    <repeater-iteration>
        <control-5>TEST</control-5>
    </repeater-iteration>
</xf:instance>
```

after "Apply" in Orbeon changes to:

```
<xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" id="repeater-template">
    <repeater-iteration>
        <control-5/>
    </repeater-iteration>
</xf:instance>
```

strangely when pasting this form into http://demo.orbeon.com/ it works fine.

Is it the problem between 4.10.2 PE and 4.10 CE versions or is it something wrong with my server?

whole form below:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>Untitled Form</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <form>
                    <section-1>

                        <repeater>
                            <repeater-iteration>
                                <control-5/>
                            </repeater-iteration>
                        </repeater>
                    </section-1>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Bindings -->
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">

                    <xf:bind id="repeater-bind" ref="repeater" name="repeater" readonly="false">
                        <xf:bind id="repeater-iteration-bind" ref="repeater-iteration" name="repeater-iteration">
                            <xf:bind id="control-5-bind" ref="control-5" name="control-5"/>
                        </xf:bind>
                    </xf:bind>
                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>

            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>a</application-name>
                    <form-name>a</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en">Untitled Form</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                    <singleton>false</singleton>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Attachments -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments>
                    <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                    <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
                </attachments>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- All form resources -->
            <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                        <control-5>
                            <label>repeater</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </control-5>
                        <section-1>
                            <label>Untitled Section</label>
                        </section-1>

                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Utility instances for services -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <request/>
            </xf:instance>

            <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <response/>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" id="repeater-template">
                <repeater-iteration>
                    <control-5>TEST</control-5>
                </repeater-iteration>
            </xf:instance>

        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                     xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>

                    <fr:grid id="repeater-control" bind="repeater-bind" repeat="content" min="1"
                             template="instance('repeater-template')">
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:input id="control-5-control" bind="control-5-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-5/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-5/hint"/>

                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:input>
                            </xh:td>
                        </xh:tr>
                    </fr:grid>
                </fr:section>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Comment: How do you set the value? What is the "Apply" button you're referring to?

Comment: I'm setting value in "Edit Source" and using "Apply" button is Source editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templates are automatically generated by Form Builder, so it is unsafe to put anything in them by editing the source.

Instead, use an "Initial Value" formula to set an initial value for that field, to `'TEST'` (with the quotes) for example, and set the "Apply Initial Value Formulas when Adding Iterations" checkbox as explained [here](http://blog.orbeon.com/2015/10/repeated-grids-and-sections-just-got.html).